# DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE and UNIX_DATE both return errors on Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The query I'm running as a test is:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_DATE(created_utc)
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_08`
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: No matching signature for function UNIX_DATE for argument types: 
INT64. Supported signature: UNIX_DATE(DATE) at [2:3]
```

I checked the datatype for the created_utc field and it's an integer. Casting and whatnot won't work either.

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNIX_DATE()` [takes a String](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#unix_date).

And `DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE()` takes an INT64.  SQL has a legacy problem of thinking of time ("date") in DAYS and not SECONDS like Unix. Thus:

```
SELECT DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(CAST(created_utc/86400 as INT64))
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_08`
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_seconds) instead

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_08`
LIMIT 5
```

Then you can use [`DATE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date) if you need date only

```
DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc))
```

Comment: That would provide for fractional dates, yes. :-)